# BigQuery - DateTime conversion - How to Exclude "T" within?

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have an **Excel** datetime format field (m/d/yyyy HH:MM:SS) which I am loading as **string** into a **BigQuery** table. I want to change this as DateTime format within BigQuery as below:

**parse_datetime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", <field_name>)**

This is returning output which has **"T"** within it (Eg: 2021-08-24T14:20:23). I don't want **"T"** but a **space** between date and time  like this (2021-08-24 14:20:23) without changing the data type.

Please let me know if you've any suggestions. Thanks in Advance!

I have an Excel datetime format field (m/d/yyyy HH:MM:SS) which I am loading as string into a BigQuery table. I want to change this as DateTime format within BigQuery as below:

parse_datetime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", <field_name>)

This is returning output which has "T" within it (Eg: 2021-08-24T14:20:23). I don't want "T" but a space between date and time  like this (2021-08-24 14:20:23) without changing the data type.

Please let me know if you've any suggestions. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a `T` in your [DateTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime) value, because this is the default output formatting for this type in BigQuery.

To see it formatted differently, you'll need to convert the format when you read the data back out. For example, use the [FORMAT_DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime) function:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", CURRENT_DATETIME())
  AS formatted;
```

Output: `2023-03-03 05:17:49`

See the above link for all the output formatting flags available in BigQuery.

Comment: format_datetime() changes the datatype to String right? Any possible way to maintain the output datatype as Datetime itself but with a space between Date and time instead of 'T'?

Comment: What are you using the output for, @KavyaB? If your output is DateTime, and you're feeding the data to another query, or another table, then it doesn't matter what the string format of the date is (it's not a string internally inside BigQuery).

However, if you're saving this out to a CSV, JSON, etc, then it will be saved as the string representation, so you will need to use FORMAT_DATETIME to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Joseph Lust
Output of my process is an input to Tableau dashboard, fyi

Comment: If Tableau is reading data as DateTime, then it shouldn't matter, but if it's reading as a string, then you likely need to format the output :)